# Can I check Salesforce CLI Release notes right within the terminal?

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, cli, commandline

I want to find and read about all the new features and enhancements in the Salesforce CLI every time I decide to upgrade to the latest. Is there a command that I can execute to read the Salesforce CLI release notes right within my command line terminal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can now read release notes right within Salesforce CLI.

To find whats changed run the below command

```
sfdx whatsnew -v latest
```

and for sf executable use

```
sf whatsnew -v latest
```

To find what's there in the next release candidate run

```
sfdx whatsnew -v rc
```

and for sf

```
sf whatsnew -v rc
```